# Creation of MapLayer failed (pyqgis)

Tags: pyqgis

I want to create a polygon with given coordinates from scratch. Doing this using the QGIS VectorLayer class gives no output. I used the example from the pyqgis cookbook, wich is creating point features and modified it to expect an polygon output . I also tried to create multiple points with this code by adding more QgsPointXY() elements but this also gives me no output.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temp", "memory")

pr = vl.dataProvider()
#pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String),
#                  QgsField("age",  QVariant.Int),
#                  QgsField("size", QVariant.Double)])
vl.updateFields() 

f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(QgsPointXY(0,0),QgsPointXY(0,10),QgsPointXY(10,10),QgsPointXY(10,0)))
#f.setAttributes(["Ada L.", 2, 0.3])
pr.addFeature(f)
vl.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

What should be done to make this code running?

My environment: Windows10, QGIS 3.10 Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a go - it works on QGIS 3.4

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temp", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
vl.updateFields()
f = QgsFeature()
pol = [[QgsPointXY(0,0),QgsPointXY(0,10),QgsPointXY(10,10),QgsPointXY(10,0)]]
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(pol))
pr.addFeature(f)
vl.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```